# Invalid instruction "targetApi", valid instructions are,Remove,replace,Stricttt

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I get this error

Invalid instruction "targetApi", valid instructions are,Remove,replace,Strict

I don't know where this error came from.

I don't know what to do, I worked so hard but this mistake was mafia

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="com.mycompany.myapp.workmanager-init"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:exported="false"
            android:multiprocess="true"
            tools:targetApi="n"/>
        
        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.SystemAlarmService"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_alarm_service_default"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:targetApi="n"/>

        <service
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="@bool/enable_system_job_service_default"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            tools:targetApi="n"/>

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable$BroadcastReceiver"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:targetApi="n"/>

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.ConstraintProxy$BatteryChargingProxy"
            android:directBootAware="false"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:targetApi="n">
```

Comment: have you tried removing   `tools:targetApi="n"`

Comment: deleted all on the page but still the same

Comment: https://notes.io/N3gJ